# Alloy nl.fokkezb.drawer widget change statusbarstyle

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy, drawer

I need to change the statusbarstyle to Black, and I don't know how... I tried to put

Index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Widget id="drawer" src="nl.fokkezb.drawer">
        <Window role="leftWindow" module="xp.ui">

        </Window>
        <NavigationWindow id="navWindow" platform="ios" role="centerWindow">
            <Window >
                <LeftNavButton>
                    <Button id="leftButton" onClick="toggleLeft">ICON</Button>
                </LeftNavButton>
                <RightNavButton>
                    <Button id="rightButton">ICON</Button>
                </RightNavButton>
            </Window>
        </NavigationWindow>
        <View platform="android" role="centerWindow">

        </View>
    </Widget>
</Alloy>
```

This is the class Index.tss

```
"#drawer": {
    openDrawerGestureMode: "OPEN_MODE_ALL",
    closeDrawerGestureMode: "CLOSE_MODE_ALL",
    leftDrawerWidth: 200,
    exitOnClose: true,
    navBarHidden: true,
    fullscreen: true,
statusBarStyle: "STATUSBAR_BLACK"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Titanium.UI.Window.statusBarStyle property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-statusBarStyle) accepts one of below values:

- [Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.DEFAULT](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-DEFAULT)
- [Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.GRAY](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-GRAY)
- [Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.GREY](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-GREY)
- [Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-LIGHT_CONTENT)
- [Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.OPAQUE_BLACK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-OPAQUE_BLACK)
- [Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.TRANSLUCENT_BLACK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar-property-TRANSLUCENT_BLACK)

In your case you can try this code:

```
"#drawer": {
    openDrawerGestureMode: "OPEN_MODE_ALL",
    closeDrawerGestureMode: "CLOSE_MODE_ALL",
    leftDrawerWidth: 200,
    exitOnClose: true,
    navBarHidden: true,
    fullscreen: true,
    statusBarStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.OPAQUE_BLACK,
}
```

Also make sure that #drawer is pointing to Window view element. I don't know how your widget drawer is working.

Comment: This works on iPad? Because I want this for an Ipad.

Comment: According to documentation this property is supported for both iPhone and iPad since Titanium SDK 3.1.3.